# Converting square wave edge timestamp data to data appropriate for plotting

Tags: pandas, bokeh

This is an example of the data I'm working with:

[image]

It's the description of a boolean square wave, with the following characteristics:

- Numbers in "Down" column are random integers, but are to be always drawn as zero
- Numbers in Up column are also random integers, but are to be always drawn as 1
- Most of the time, "Up" and "Down" alternate regularly, but once in a while, an extra "Down" or "Up" can be present.
- delay between transitions is irregular - values in the "Time" column should be considered random, but sequential (sorted).

Here's the bokeh representation I'm after:[image]

Seeing both the original points (including the repeating ones, like the one as t=1.2) and the line overlay is required.

My understanding is that the easiest way is to interpolate one point between every pair, with y-value being the Up/Down value of the previous point and x-value from the next point. Then, in bokeh, plot both the original data as a scatter and Data+InterpolatedData as a line plot. This means two different glyphs in the plot, which I'd rather avoid (to be able to use the new legend.click_policy = "hide"), but is tolerable.

The interpolation is easily achieved with regular python code, but I'd prefer to find a way to do it with pandas, for code uniformity. Is pandas an appropriate tool for this kind of interpolation?

An optimal solution would lead to a single glyph in bokeh. I'm willing to sacrifice performance to achieve this.
A good solution replaces my pure python code with pandas code.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a complete script that works for Bokeh.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("signal.html")

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    time=[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8], 
    down=[19371, None, None, 38175, None],
    up=[None, 36823, 91046, None, 47722]
))

data['mapped'] = data.up.isnull()

# This computes the "step" data
x, y = [], []
prev = -1
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row.mapped != prev and prev>=0:
        x.append(row.time)
        y.append(prev)
    x.append(row.time)
    y.append(int(row.mapped))
    prev = int(row.mapped)

p = figure()
p.line(x=x, y=y, legend="signal")
p.circle(x=data.time, y=data.mapped, legend="signal")

p.legend.click_policy="hide"

show(p)
```

This yields the following Bokeh plot with interactive legend:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, with lots to learn from on both Pandas and Bokeh, in particular that it's possible to merge multiple glyphs by giving them the same legend name. Thanks! However, your answer has a big drawback - it's significantly slower than my current code: about 2.4s on my 7700 points test file, compared to around 1.4s for mine. I suspect that the 7700 calls to boolean_map() is what hurts yours. I'll be posting my code as an answer, in case it's of interest.

Comment: quite possibly, the data size was not stated so I just opted for the "simplest" thing. I've updated the answer so that it might be more efficient.

Comment: It should be down.isnull() or up.notnull(), but for a reason I can't explain, it still takes the same 2.4s. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. Please note that matplotlib was used directly and not pandas (which actually uses matplotlib) to plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Map the data with pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv('wave_data.csv', sep=';')

def boolean_map(row):
   if pd.notnull(row.Down):
      return 0
   else:
      return 1

data['BooleanMapped'] = data.apply(boolean_map, axis=1)
```

[image: Output]

Plot the data:

```
x = list(data['Time'])
y = list(data['BooleanMapped'])
plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.5)
plt.xlim(0.9, 2)
plt.step(x, y, where='post')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph Example]

Comment: Question was regarding how to create an interactive plot using Bokeh, not Matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting to see that matplotlib has an [API](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) for this exact use-case. However, I'm quite bound to Bokeh plots already, so my pure Python solution will have to do for now, especially since benchmarking it has proven it to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As announced in a comment, here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    import timeit
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()

    import io
    import os
    import sys
    import math

    import pandas

    from bokeh.io import output_file, show
    from bokeh.plotting import figure

    output_file("signal.html")

    def fillSquareWave(xi, downi, upi):
        resultx = [0,]
        resulty = [0,]
        lasty = 0
        for x, down, up in zip(xi, downi, upi):
            if (math.isnan(down)) and (math.isnan(up)):
                # no dropna() at pandas level, since it'd drop if EITHER is a nan (we only drop if BOTH are)
                pass
            else:
                # append extra point
                resultx.append(x)
                resulty.append(lasty)

                # append real, current point
                resultx.append(x)
                if (not math.isnan(down)) and (math.isnan(up)):
                    resulty.append(0)
                    lasty = 0
                elif (math.isnan(down)) and (not math.isnan(up)):
                    resulty.append(1)
                    lasty = 1
                else:
                    print("x: ", x, " down: ", down, " up: ", up)
                    assert(False)
        return resultx, resulty

    sourcefile = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
    bothpts = pandas.read_csv(sourcefile, usecols=['Time', 'down', 'up'])
    uppts = pandas.read_csv(sourcefile, usecols=['Time', 'up']) 
    uppts.dropna(inplace=True)
    uppts['up'] = 1
    downpts = pandas.read_csv(sourcefile, usecols=['Time', 'down']) 
    downpts.dropna(inplace=True)
    downpts['down'] = 0

    php = figure()
    php.scatter(uppts['Time'], uppts['up'], legend='up',)
    php.scatter(downpts['Time'], downpts['down'], legend='down')
    xdata, ydata = fillSquareWave(bothpts['Time'], bothpts['down'], bothpts['up'])
    php.line(xdata, ydata, legend='overlay')
    php.legend.click_policy = "hide"

    show(php)

    print("Rendered in %.2fs" % (timeit.default_timer() - start_time))
```

This code generate a plot that slightly differs from the question - it starts the drawing at (0,0) and not at the coordinates of the first point in the CSV file.

**Edit:** it is possible to remove the multiple read_csv() calls with the following code, but the execution time is basically unchanged.

```
    bothpts = pandas.read_csv(sourcefile, usecols=['Time', 'down', 'up'])
    uppts = copy(bothpts)
    del uppts['down']
    uppts.dropna(inplace=True)
    uppts['up'] = 1
    downpts = copy(bothpts)
    del downpts['up']
    downpts.dropna(inplace=True)
    downpts['down'] = 0
```